# Cannot connect 2 different monitors through separate usb c cables

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, dual-screen

I've tried everything.

My setup is:

1 x MacBookPro 15" 2017

2 x Philips Brilliance 279P1/00

I'm trying to connect both of them through the USB C cables they came with.
I can only connect one at a time.

Before you suggest, yes I've tried everything that can be found through google searches and searches on this stackexchange:

- clicking on Detect Displays
- turning the power on/off on external monitor
- keeping my macbook through a separate charger
- going in sleep mode
- upgrade to Big Sur
- not sleeping enough

Comment: Do they work individually? (i.e. plug in one monitor with cable A - test that works, then unplug it, and unplug the second monitor with cable B - test that works)

Comment: Are you connecting both monitors directly to the MacBook Pro? - Or are you somehow trying to daisy-chain them? (not supported)

Comment: They work individually, the cables are USB c-c , provided by Philips. I am not trying to daisy chain them, I'm trying to connect them both simultaneously, in parallel in separate ports of the MacBook

Comment: And when you say you cannot connect them - what happens exactly? - Can you plug them in? Does one work and the other doesn't? - Or both have "no signal" / blank screen? - Do you get some sort of error message? - What does System Preferences > Displays show you?

Comment: They only "work" one at a time. So, for example, if I start with both plugged in, one of them will open up.  One the other one I will have "No video input(USB C)" .

Comment: Have you tried plugging one in on the left side of the laptop, and the other on the right hand side? … what does System Preferences > Displays show when both are plugged in?

Comment: Hah, yes I've tried in all .. 12 combinations (if my math is good). What basically happens is this: When I plug the second one in macbook, my first monitor and macbook go dark like it is doing something, the other display very briefly appears under "Arragnement" (but nothing on the screen) and then dissapears for good.

Comment: Have you got a different monitor you can try with? Is there anything you can set in the setup menu on the display you have now? (I.e. with buttons on the monitor itself)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have another monitor. I can only select Language and Video Input (HDMI 1,2, Display Port and USB-C). I've managed to connect it using an old adapter dongle with HDMI port (so MAC-> USBC -> USBC TO HDMI ADAPTER => HDMI =>Monitor). But I do not want this solution, I want to use the full capabilities of the docking station inside the monitor which come through USB-C.  Thanks for your patience and time

Comment: What does the Console app say when you plug in the second monitor? Perhaps capture changed output from running "dmesg" in the terminal just before and just after connecting the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup with a 16" MacBook Pro 2019 and similarly experienced that only one of the two Philips can be connected by USB-C to USB-C cable for its DisplayPort.

I have to connect the other Philips using a USB-C to DisplayPort cable or USB-C to HDMI cable. The second display works at full resolution with either cable.

I can still use the USB-C hub of the second monitor by connecting the USB-C to USB-C cable in addition to the USB-C to DisplayPort/HDMI cable, though that does use up one additional USB-C port on my mac.

Running Windows on Bootcamp, neither Philips are detected over the USB-C to USB-C cables. I have to connect BOTH with separate USB-C to DisplayPort/HDMI cables. Though, as before, leaving the USB-C to USB-C connected does allow me to use both monitors as USB-C hubs, but taking up all four USB-C ports of the mac.

Comment: After upgrading to Monterey, I no longer need a separate USB-C to DisplayPort cable to use both monitors as extended monitors.